# Font changing, true or false?

Tags: discussion

On Stack Overflow, I seem to notice a font style change. Is this true? I am using Chrome and it does seem to be true. But, I'm not sure. Can some verify this as fact?

Comment: ... I'm betting you're on Chrome stable and just seeing the new font stuff Chrome did in 36?

Answer (score 6):

I thought it changed too. Then someone clued me in to the use of DirectWrite for font rendering in the latest Chrome update.

[image: to which I said...]

Comment: http://superuser.com/search?q=chrome+37+font

Comment: Sober all the time?  Unacceptable.  Uninstalling.