# Why is the font thinner now, or is it?

Tags: discussion, design

Don't know whether to believe my eyes, but the font used in tags and community bulletin and even the font size of this editor seems to have reduced or has become thinner.

Have they really become thinner, or is it just an illusion?

Comment: Perhaps you installed a new font recently? The CSS will pick the best available font from several options; installing an additional font can mean that that font is now being picked over another.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've definitely not downloaded any new fonts.. Inspecting gives me `font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;`

Comment: [Are you using Chrome?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270128/font-changing-true-or-false)

Comment: So, it'll pick Arial, then if not present, Liberation Sans, then DejaVu Sans, etc.

Comment: @Antony: ah, it's a platform and browser specific change then. That change doesn't apply to the Mac version, only Windows, which explains why I didn't see any change.

Comment: @Antony  Its not that I've been using some other browser and immediately switched over to chrome. I use only google chrome.

Comment: Go here for the solution: http://superuser.com/questions/803637/how-to-disable-directwrite-in-google-chrome-37. I had the same problem last night; thought I was *way* too drunk.